# Not able to Enable Query Accelerator for DB2 for IDAA from Java

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

I'm trying to execute SQL queries in query accelerator mode from Java using plain JDBC approach. That is, creating a connection from `DriverManager` and executed query. But it's getting failed throwing `com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException`

I set the special parameter in connection URL as mentioned in IBM docs for this.

Tables are already moved to IBM DB2 Analytics Accelerator (IDAA) server and I'm able to execute queries with accelerated mode from AQT tool (My DB client tool) and it is running ultra fast.

I've used `db2jcc4` driver `Type4` and the connection URL and Connection class is given below:

```java
public class ConnectionManager {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConnectionManager.class);

    private static String url = "jdbc:db2://myIP:myPort/myDBName:specialRegisters=CURRENT QUERY ACCELERATION=ELIGIBLE";
    private static String driverName = "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver";
    private static String username = "user";
    private static String password = "pwd";
    private static Connection con;
    private static String urlstring;

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            Class.forName(driverName);
            try {
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                // log an exception. fro example:
                System.out.println("Failed to create the database connection.");
                throw ex;
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            // log an exception. for example:
            System.out.println("Driver not found.");
            throw ex;
        }
        return con;
    }
}
```

Is there anything I missed or did wrong?

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: [jcc][10165][10051][4.24.92] Invalid database URL syntax: jdbc:db2://IP:Port/DBName:specialRegisters=CURRENT QUERY ACCELERATION=ELIGIBLE. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b6.a(b6.java:810)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b6.a(b6.java:66)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b6.a(b6.java:98)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.tokenizeURLProperties(DB2Driver.java:950)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:413)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:113)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at colruyt.spcpocxpsejb.util.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:38)
    at colruyt.spcpocxpsejb.util.TestUtility.testAOT(TestUtility.java:98)
    at colruyt.spcpocxpsejb.util.TestUtility.main(TestUtility.java:25)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349)
    at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:377)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.tokenizeURLProperties(DB2Driver.java:938)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: Please provide the full exception stacktrace

Comment: Updated in Post

Comment: I don't know DB2 myself, but why do you think that is a valid URL? Both the colon (`:`) after `DBName` and the presence of two `=` look suspicious to me.

Comment: This is must be valid connection string as its mentioned in DB2 doc http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27038078

Comment: Looking at that link, you are missing a `;` at the end of your URL

Comment: What a catch !!! Your are impossible...Saved my day...Thank you brother..Kudos